# how can controller call model in plugin? (cakephp 2.x(2.6)) (app -> plugin -> PluginName -> Controller)

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I want to call model in the plugin but I want to call this controller in the plugin.

-> app -> Plugin -> Admin -> Model -> exampleModel.php

-> app -> Plugin -> Admin -> Contoller (call model)

I tried them

```
$this->loadModel("ModelName");
```

or

```
$this->loadModel("PluginName.ModelName");
```

returning the result app -> model -> exampleModel.php

How do I call it?

Comment: Are you load plugin in bootstrap.php ?

Comment: Yes i load plugin in bootstrap.php.

CakePlugin::Load('Admin');

app -> config -> bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems from `app -> model -> exampleModel.php` vs `Plugin -> Admin -> Model -> exampleModel.php` that you have two identical classes in those two directories, but that is not supported, I'm afraid:

> Due to PHP lacking namespaces in older versions you cannot have the same class, or same filename, in your plugins. Even if it is two different plugins. So use unique classes and filenames, possible prefixing the class and filename with the plugin name.

source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html

Comment: Okey. Thank your answer. but there is more than one this code($this->loadModel("PluginName.ModelName");) in my controller functions. if this code is only, this is worked. example  =>    class exmapleController extends AdminAppController{ function oneFunction(){ $this->loadModel("PluginName.ModelName"); } function twoFunction(){ $this->loadModel("PluginName.ModelName"); } }

Comment: better way to introduce models into yours controllers is the 
`public $uses = array('ContactManager.Contact');` clause instead of `Controller::loadModel()`

in your place I would start from the book on plugins here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html

-- the code fragments there will help you

Comment: yes i am use  public $uses array("pluginName.currentModel","pluginName.useModell"); .. result success. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Write in bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
$Setting = ClassRegistry::init('Configuration');
```